# Migrating from SQL 2012 to SQL 2014 "XCOPY" Userdb:s

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2014, xcopy, migrating

Scenario:

Original machine with WS 2008 and SQL 2012 => Cloned 
Cloned Patched => WS 2012R2 and SQL 2014

is it possible to run the WS 2008 and SQL 2012 for some time and just use xcopy for the user databases to the WS 2012R2 and SQL 2014 enviroment. Start the Sql 2014 and up and running?

Comment: Can you elaborate on this `is it possible to run the WS 2008 and SQL 2012 for some time`

Comment: as well as  this `Start the Sql 2014 and up and running?`

Comment: After cloning,  the production enviroment will keep running while testing the clone.  "After the tests is it possible to stop the sql on the clone use xcopy on the user db:s and fire upp the sql on the klone without attach or restore"

After that the system will go live again on the Internet